# An example of a map that is not unramified in a specific way

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples

In Milne - Étale cohomology, the definition of an unramified morphism is given as follows (here I am using standard notation for sheaves, stalks, maximal ideals in the stalk and residue fields):

Let $f: Y \rightarrow X$ be a map of schemes, locally of finite type, and let $y \in Y$. Write $x = f(x)$. We say $f$ is *unramified* at $y$ if

1. The image of $m_x$ in $\mathcal{O}_{Y, y}$ generates $m_y$.
2. The resulting map of fields $\kappa(x) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}/m_x \mathcal{O}_{Y,y} \overset{!}= \kappa(y)$ is a finite separable field extension.

My question now is: what is an example of such a map where condition 1. is satisfied, but the resulting field extension in 2. is *infinite*? Since this finiteness condition is part of the definition, such an example probably exists.. This is just out of curiosity and to build more intuition for the concept.

Some remarks:
Since the question is local we can reduce to $X$ and $Y$ affine and $f$ of finite type. Then the map $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \rightarrow \Gamma(Y, \mathcal{O}_{Y})$ makes the latter into a finitely generated algebra of the former, which implies that in fact $\kappa(y)$ is a finitely generated $\kappa(x)$ algebra. In particular if this field extension would be algebraic, it would be finite, so an example like the one I am looking for must be a transcedental extension. (In fact I have seen that Hartshorne requires 2. only to be an algebraic extension, which by the above remark is equivalent.)

I have tried numerous examples but somehow satisfying condition 1. automatically implied the field extension to be finite. Maybe the problem is that I worked only with varieties (in my case separable and of finite type over $k = \overline{k}$. A proof that in that case 1. would imply that the extenson in 2. is finite would be very interesting in its own right!

Comment: I mean, the counterexample is going to have to be semi-contrived. For example, if $f$ is also locally quasi-finite then it's not hard to see that 1) implies the finiteness in 2). I feel like in most reasonable situations 1. should imply locally quasi-finite. Like, suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is surjective map of varieties (we can just replace $Y$ by its image), then $\dim X\geqslant \dim Y$. But, let $y$ be a closed point of $Y$ and let $x$ be a point of $X$ mapping to it. Necessarily $x$ is closed. 1. then implies that $\mathrm{codim}_x X=\dim X\leqslant \mathrm{codim}_y Y=\dim Y$.

Comment: So, this implies that $\dim X=\dim Y$. so if $f$ satisfies mild conditions (e.g. flat) then the fibers will be zero-dimensional, and so $f$ will be quasi-finite and then, as I mentioned before, this should show that 1) implies the finiteness in 2). **EDIT:** when I say varieties I mean the usual list (separated, finite type, reduced, equidimensional,..) **EDIT EDIT** I made a boo-boo above. What I should have said is take $x$ a closed point, then $f(x)$ is a closed point and then proceeded. It's non-sense that any closed point has only closed point preimages.

Comment: Hi @AlexYoucis ! Thanks for your comments. But I just realised something, how about the map induced by $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}(T)$? Isn't it an example? Its fibers are obviously finite, which is quasi-finiteness of the map by definition right? So why does your logic not apply in this case?

Comment: Those aren't varieties. And that map isn't locally of finite type :P A locally finite type map between fields is finite.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Woops I messed up the definition of finite type maps. ^^ But that makes me think, since the map $\kappa(x) \rightarrow \kappa(y) $ is of finite type doesn't that already imply it is finite? Or am I being silly again?

Comment: Why is the map $k(y)\to k(x)$ finite type? Let's deal with the affine case, say $X=\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ and $Y=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. We then have the map $\mathrm{Spec}(k(y))\to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ where let's say that $y$ represents the prime $\mathfrak{p}$ so that $k(y)=A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$. Clearly then the pullback along this point, i.e. the algebra $B\otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ is finite type. But, this map is 'morally' the product of $B_\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{q}$ where $\mathfrak{q}$ travels over the primes lying over $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: and if we know that $\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{q}B_\mathfrak{q}$ so that $B_\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{q}$ equals $B_\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{q}B_\mathfrak{q}=k(x)$ (if $x=\mathfrak{q}$) which mean we win. But, without this I don't see how you conclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be a non perfect field of characteristic $p\gt 0$, $a\in k$ an element with no $p$-th root in $k$ and let $$K=k[\sqrt[p] a]=\frac {k[T]}{\langle T^p-a\rangle}$$ We  thus obtain a non-separable extension $k\to K$, of dimension $[K:k]=p$.
The associated finite morphism of one point affine schemes $$f: \operatorname {Spec}(K)\to \operatorname {Spec}(k)$$ satisfies 1. but not 2. at their unique point.

**Edit**
Here is (as was actually required!) an example with $\kappa(x)\to \kappa (y)$ 
 infinite.
Let $\mathbb Z_p \to\mathbb Z_p[T] $ be the inclusion and let $$f:Y=\operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb Z_p[T])\to X=\operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb Z_p)$$ be the associated morphism of finite type between the corresponding  affine schemes.
Taking $y= p\mathbb Z_p[T] \in Y$ and $x=p\mathbb Z_p \in X$, we get an example where 1. is satisfied at $y$ ,  but 2. is not   since $\kappa (x)=\mathbb F_p\to \kappa (y)=\mathbb F_p(T)$ is not finite.

Comment: I feel like we've had this encounter recently :) The OP was curious about the non-finiteness in 2. not the separability, I believe.

Comment: Thanks! But this extension is still finite right? I was actually looking for an infinite extension (not necessarily inseparable).

Comment: Dear @1Alex and Joachim: sorry, you are right: I skipped that part of the question !

Comment: I have now made another attempt in an edit...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Nice example! That is extremely easy. Do you agree that any examples with varieties are bound to be pathological?

Comment: Dear @Alex: yes, I agree.

Comment: Hi Georges and @AlexYoucis , how about the map $k \rightarrow k[x]$, the generic point of $\mathbb{A}^1$ is mapped to the unique point of $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$, resulting in $k = k_{(0)} \rightarrow k[x]_{(0)} = k(x)$ where 1. is satisfied but 2. not since the extension is infinite?

Comment: It is basically your example Georges but then with $\mathbb{Z}_p$ replaced by $k$. Thanks in any case for your great answer!